# Building a (non-bootstrap) WP site and want to include a bootstrap plugin

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress

I want to use the Bootstrap ScrollSpy in my Wordpress site, but the theme I'm working with does not use Bootstrap as a foundation. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably implement it by downloading the Bootstrap library via a plugin. Try installing this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/

The author says that ScrollSpy is included: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/scrollspy